# Can't figure out why some variables won't initialize

Tags: java, compiler-errors, return

```
public static String produceAnswer(String y) {
    int space1Location = y.indexOf(" ");
    String value1 = y.substring(0, space1Location - 1);
    String value2 = y.substring(space1Location + 3);
    String operator = y.substring(space1Location + 1, space1Location + 2);
    int underLocation = value2.indexOf("_");
    int slashLocation = value2.indexOf("/");
    String wholeNum;
    String numerator;
    String denominator;
    if(underLocation != -1) {
        wholeNum = value2.substring(0, underLocation);
        numerator = value2.substring(underLocation + 1, slashLocation);
        denominator = value2.substring(slashLocation + 1);
    }
    else if(underLocation == -1 && slashLocation != -1) {
        numerator = value2.substring(0, slashLocation);
        denominator = value2.substring(slashLocation + 1);
        wholeNum = "0";
    }
    else if(underLocation == -1 && slashLocation == -1) {
        wholeNum = value2;
        numerator = "0";
        denominator = "1";
    }
    return "whole:" + wholeNum + " numerator:" + numerator + " denominator:" + denominator;
}
```

The return statement in my code doesn't work for some reason. It says that the variables haven't been initialized, which doesn't make sense to me, because I definitely initialized them in the if statements right? What's wrong here?

Comment: Which variables haven't been initialized? Can you be more specific

Comment: And what, if no if condition evaluates to true?

Comment: The variables 'wholeNum', 'numerator', and 'denominator' all apparently haven't been initialized.

Comment: Read the JLS chapter on reachability and definite assignment. :)

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know one of the `if` conditions is always true, and if that is the case, why do you have a test on the last `else if`?

Comment: Hint: why are you testing `if(underLocation == -1 && slashLocation == -1)`?

Answer (score 6):

When you write an `if-else-if...` statement without a final `else`, the compiler doesn't know if one of the conditions is guaranteed to be `true`, which means it doesn't know for sure that your local variables will be initialized.

You should change the last `else if` to `else`.

```
if(underLocation != -1) {
    wholeNum = value2.substring(0, underLocation);
    numerator = value2.substring(underLocation + 1, slashLocation);
    denominator = value2.substring(slashLocation + 1);
} else if (underLocation == -1 && slashLocation != -1) {
    numerator = value2.substring(0, slashLocation);
    denominator = value2.substring(slashLocation + 1);
    wholeNum = "0";
} else {
    wholeNum = value2;
    numerator = "0";
    denominator = "1";
}
```

Or even:

```
if (underLocation != -1) {
    wholeNum = value2.substring(0, underLocation);
    numerator = value2.substring(underLocation + 1, slashLocation);
    denominator = value2.substring(slashLocation + 1);
} else if (slashLocation != -1) {
    numerator = value2.substring(0, slashLocation);
    denominator = value2.substring(slashLocation + 1);
    wholeNum = "0";
} else {
    wholeNum = value2;
    numerator = "0";
    denominator = "1";
}
```

since if the first condition is `false`, we already know that `underLocation` is guaranteed to be `-1` in the second condition, so it's sufficient to test that `slashLocation != -1`.

Comment: You don't need that `underLocation == -1`.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it.